# Format datetime labels to include weekday name for pandas plot

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to add the corresponding weekday names (Mon, Tues, etc.) to the xlabels for a pandas timeseries plot.

[image: timeline graph]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as p
import datetime

dates = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime.today().date(), periods=10, freq='D')
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10),index=dates,columns=['A'])
a = data['A'].plot()
p.tight_layout()
p.show()
```

I have tried adjusting the formatting using:

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
formatter = DateFormatter('%a %d-%m-%Y')
a.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

But this does not work, leading to incorrect day and year.

It seems there should be a very simple solution, but I cannot find it.

Comment: seems like `dates.weekday` should be able to help in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I thought would work but didn't:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax = data.A.plot()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda d, _: d.strftime('%a')))
```

or

```
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(data.index, data.A)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda d, _: d.strftime('%a')))
```

These both go wrong in different ways. It seems the formatter inputs turn out to be `floats` rather than dates in both cases. In the first the function only gets applied to the first and last ticks. You can see this by passing

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda d, _: d)
```

Here's a solution which is pretty flexible:

```
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(data.index, data.A)
ticks = ax.set_xticklabels([d.strftime('%a') for d in data.index])
```

You can swap the list comprehension in the last line for whatever you like.

EDIT:

I think I've figure out what these numbers representing the `xticks` mean.

```
In [37]: 
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(data.index, data.A)
print  ax.get_xticks()
[ 735824.  735825.  735826.  735827.  735828.  735829.  735830.  735831.
  735832.  735833.]
```

These seem to represent the number of days since the start of 1 AD: According to this: http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/seconds-days-since-year-0.php

"There are 736189 days between 0000-00-00 and today (Aug 14, 2015)."

Which is exactly 735824 (the first tick) + 365. So far so bad. 
You could (I won't bother) write a function to convert this number and ones like into dates. Another approach would be:

```
def get_day(tick):
    date = dates[0] + datetime.timedelta(tick - ticks[0])
    return date.strftime('%a')

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(data.index, data.A)
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda tick, _: get_day(tick)))
```

Again, you can sub the date format you want into `get_day`. Not sure if this will solve the panning/zooming problem but at least it gives a way of setting the tick labels using a function.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you zoom or pan the plot, the labels change and do not align with the data points.

Comment: I don't have any experience with panning or zooming with `matplotlib`. Not sure what to do then.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer to include a solution using a (very hacky) function. Maybe that will solve the panning/zooming problem

Comment: My normal use case is to plot timeline data, then interact with it via the pop-up GUI (pan and zoom), to explore regions of interest. Alas, I suspect this is a bug - I would expect your first solution to work with this behaviour. but I don't have the time to investigate. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: No worries. It was annoying and I wanted to figure out this strange behaviour.